# rxvt and Inconsolata (a font)

Tags: terminal, fonts, rxvt

Is it possible to use the rxvt terminal emulator with [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html)?  Is it possible to use any TrueType fonts with rxvt? I'd like to use rxvt but would love to use my own fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rxvt` does not support TrueType, but there is a fork [`rxvt-unicode`](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode) (or `urxvt`) which can.

urxvt(1) gives two examples:

```
urxvt -fn "xft:Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:pixelsize=15"
urxvt -fn "9x15bold,xft:Bitstream Vera Sans Mono"
```

Comment: How do you find the format for the fonts inside the quotes?

Comment: check the urxvt(1) man page, the section 'RESOURCES' has further explanation how to configure the font selection. Probably something like `urxvt -fn "xft:Inconsolata"`.

Comment: @CoreyFarwell sometimes UNIX tools and their manuals are referred to by `name(number)` where number is the section of the `man` manuals where its manual is. So `man number name` will give you the manual this is about.

Comment: Can't this be configured from `.Xresources`?